# rails bug nomethod error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my controller I use the following code to send all Articles to the View

```
class Admin::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  layout 'adminpanel'

  before_action :require_user
  before_action :require_admin

  def index
    @articles = News.all
  end
end
```

But every time I restart my rails server it shows me a nil:nilClass error for some reason.
When I've got this error I have to open my controller, delete a letter in that, rewrite it and save it (Nothing is changed, just rewrote the letter to be able to save) but I don't know why this happens. I've got this

> News.all

in another controller which is on the root route of rails

Here is a screenshot of the error:
[image: error]

Thanks for further help!

Comment: what is the mean for "delete a letter in that"?

Comment: Just delete anything in that file like "News.all" removing the l at the end and rewriting the l so its "News.all" again so I can save the file again

Comment: Are you sure your controller code is being run?

Comment: My routes.rb says `get 'admin/articles' => 'admin/articles#index'`

Comment: That only says that it should be getting called. If you put a breakpoint in there does it get hit? Do you have another file somewhere that is redefining Admin::ArticlesController

Comment: When I print out `debug @news` that works, it shows everything o.0

Answer (score 1):

I have ever got that `count` couldn't run in my rails 4.
You can use

```
<% if @articles.size != 0 %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<% if @articles.present? %>
<% end %>
```

I hope this help you

Comment: Why Article? My model is called "News" and in another  controller that works without a doubt, also News.new and such all work but only News.all makes trouble

Comment: Ok, sorry. I don't mean too. I thought, you have problem with your `@articles.count`. You can change into `@articles.present?`. It means, the `@articles.count != 0.

Comment: That isn't my problem at all, Ive heard about all that. But my @articles DO exist, but somehow it doesnt load until i resave one of my files in my app and that's so weird ... Since that News is a model it SHOULD exist at all times, but it says it doesn't

Comment: I mean your model. and then, Have you tried to run `News.all` in your console?

Comment: News.all shows all the conten I need to know, just in the view it doesn't work somehow

Comment: It's very strange. Perhaps, the plural News class can be a cause of your problem. Think twice to change your News class into Article. :)

Comment: It works on another controller and View, no need to change it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90115/discussion-between-muhamad-akbar-bin-widayat-and-splinti).

Answer (score 0):

When something doesn't exist you can't call a method on it.

This means that `@articles` doesn't have a value.

IRB Example:

```
2.1.2 :004 > a=[1,2]
 => [1, 2] 
2.1.2 :005 > a.count
 => 2 
2.1.2 :006 > a=nil
 => nil 
2.1.2 :007 > a.count
NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for nil:NilClass
        from (irb):7
        from /home/durrantm/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Fixing your problem will depend on what code you have in your controllers and models and migrations and views.  I would compare to sources like http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form (onwards).

Comment: Whenever I call News.all in the Rails console it shows me the content

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you need to have some conditional logic to determine if you actually have any articles to publish.

I would do the following:

```
<% if @articles.any? %>
   <% @articles.each do |article| %>
      <%= article.title %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The error is basically that `nil:nilClass` means your app has not populated the variable you're trying to effect methods on.

--

As a side note, it's bad practice (although not "wrong" by any degree) to call your model "News". If you followed Rails principles doggedly, you'd have to make it singular, as well as a description of what's inside the model, in your case `Article`.